# Executing code snippet on server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to execute a code snippet that creates new sites, which is similar to this:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPWebCollection subSites = mySite.Webs;
string currentTemplate = mySite.WebTemplate;

string siteUrl = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
string siteTitle = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
string siteDescription = TextBox3.Text.ToString();

subSites.Add(siteUrl, siteTitle, siteDescription, 1033, 
   currentTemplate, true, false);
```

When I create a webpart with that code, deploy it to my SharePoint server, and add the webpart to a page, all I get is a text with the name of the application. How can I execute this code once it's deployed as a webpart?

Comment: It sounds like the web part was not deployed correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

1. Create a new visual webpart in vs2010
2. Drag and drop a button onto the webpart control
3. double click the button to create a handler
4. Put in your code
5. Deploy, add to page and click button

If you have any issues debug the button in visual studio and see whats going on (you need to attach to w3wp.exe)